# Pass variable to method ( here position()) JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to pass a variable into a method, here specifically the position(). All their examples use strings of fixed values.

I have two variables (varHorizontal, varVertical) both integers

```
$(this).position({
    "my": "center center",
    "at": varHorizontal varVertical,
    //also tried "at": varHorizontal+'px' varVertical+'px', 
    "of": $('#parentDiv')
});
```

I have looked for syntax rules and i have tried various combinations with '' etc, but no luck.

How can I pass variables into the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate them as a single string:

```
"at": varHorizontal + ' ' + varVertical,
```

Comment: i have to wait 11 minutes to accept, have already checked and your answer is of course fine, thanks!! have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Use Array like this:

```
"at": [varHorizontal , varVertical],
```